# Installed services

Tags: linux, services

Is there a way to list all services on a VM that were added manually to the system ?

I'd like to easily generate a list of the services installed by users.
I thought of creating **list A** by listing all services first.
Then create **list B** by listing all the default services for that particular OS.
Then create **list C** = **list A**-**list B**

This solution forces me to create **list B** everytime I stumble across another OS which is the least automatable task.
Is there a better way?

Comment: The easiest approach might be to add some formality to your systems administration processes, documenting applications and tools added to each system.

Comment: Would be a good thing to do but hey once some systems are left undocumented, they're not gonna document themselves. As for audit purposes I still think it would be useful to have a tool like this.